# Single folder should be available to all users In an Organisation

Tags: c#, .net, onedrive, office-addins

I am working on a Slide management application for a organisation, Each user in the organisation should be able to access folder(Folder A) in one Drive Business Account, Sometime work on the same Presentation/file, edit, copy Presentation in application and upload Presentation to the same folder(Folder A) in the one Drive. And it means that folder(Folder A) should be available to all users In the Organisation(Which means like a repository). Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please explain, how this question is related to C# and .NET? Are you trying this with your own application?

Comment: I am using Power Point Add-in Application in c#